# Select record from multiple database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 and asp.net for C#.

Currently I'm doing an intranet. It consists of many modules inside intranet. Each module uses its own database. Normally I will using connection string for calling to the database.

I plan to do a main page to manage all pending tasks inside each module. Means on the main page, I will show all the pending tasks of all modules. Since they are all using different connection strings, what approaches can be used to achieve this?

The example below show how I access database through single connection string:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

string strsql = " select * from User "; 

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strsql, connectionString);

con.Open();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
con.Close();
con.Dispose();
```

Comment: Instead of defining `Initial Catalog` in your `ConnectionString` you can leave it and in your `CommandString`s you can make a query on a specific database like this: `select * from [YOUR_DATABASE].[dbo].[User]`.

Comment: If you have different databases, you have two options: create a linked servers and join them in a stored procedure on one of the database, or fetch the data from both databases in your code, one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Create a proc where you can call table of different database with respective Db names.

```
create proc proc_name
as begin
 select * from [DB_name1].dbo.tablename
 union all
 select * from [DB_name2].dbo.tablename
end
```

now call the proc from your code behind.

No matter what ever db name in your connection string,still you can access

Note: check your DB has rights to access other DB.